# Howto see if word have converted / repaird documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, ole

I there a way to see if a file have been converted due to damaged file or wrong format.

What I do is automatically turn documents into tiff, from documents supported by MS word. What I did was I changed a bmp file into a doc file, and Word opened it and send it to print, and it became a 106 paged tiff.

Is there a way to see in word that file have been converted or is there a technique for that.

The code I have now.

```
        Document Doc;
        Application word = new Application();
        try
        {

            word.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;

            Doc = word.Documents.Open(LocationAndFile, PasswordDocument: "BSpw", ReadOnly: true);

            word.ActivePrinter = "TIFF Image Printer 10.0";
            Doc.PrintOut(); //printout untested for now
            Doc.Close(false);

        }
        catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex)
        {

            word.Quit();
            releaseObject(word);
            return new ReturnInfo(LocationAndFile, true, ex.ErrorCode);
        }

        word.Quit();
        releaseObject(Doc);
        releaseObject(word);
```

The try catch is for stopping passworded documents, I hoped it would catch broken files but it just attempt to convert em. It does not matter if it prints a page that was converted, but I want to know it so I can list the file afterwards to make sure it looks normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Word Object Model page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/microsoft.office.interop.word.document_members.aspx), there is *no* member to verify whether a document has been repaired.

So, no, this would not be possible.

Comment: hmm, is there no way to use the dialog boxes, with out them freeze my automation.